# How I can replace every first character of the string in the column in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which has sales amount that start with dollar sign like `$123`, I want to remove this `$` from the whole column. I am trying like this ->

```
val sale2=sale1.withColumn("SaleAmount", regexp_replace(sale1("SalesAmount"), "$", ""))
```

Output result is same as input: `$123`

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$` in Regex represents end-of-line.  To specify a literal `$`, escape it like `\\$`.  If you want to replace only the leading `$`, the pattern should be `^\\$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `substr` function to that where you can pass the start position and the end position and create a new column in the dataframe or replace the value of the same column in dataframe by applying transformation.

**First Approach:**

```
//Source data
val df = Seq(("$120"),("$135"),("$4500")).toDF("Value")
//using expr with substr function
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df1 = df.withColumn("test",expr("substr(Value, 2, length(Value))"))
```

**Second Approach:**

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("Test",$"Value".substr(lit(2), length($"Value")-1))
```

In the second approach we are not using `expr` we are using `substr` operation on the column itself.

You can see the output as below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `replace` for replacements of string patterns. `regexp_replace` is for replacing regex patterns, and `$` has a special meaning in regex (end of string).

```
val sale2 = sale1.withColumn(
    "SaleAmount",
    expr("replace(SalesAmount, '$', '')")
)
```